# Simple definition of factorizer

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I am reading the great post from Bartosz Milewski about [Products and Coproducts](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/07/products-and-coproducts/).

Consider following functions:

```
factorizer :: (c -> a) -> (c -> b) -> (c -> (a, b))
factorizer p q = \x -> (p x, q x)
```

Is `(c -> (a, b))` the factorizer? If yes, why? Honestly, for me the sample is just a function, that expects two higher order function. I can't see the pattern of the `Product`.

The next sample:

```
factorizer :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
factorizer i j (Left a)  = i a
factorizer i j (Right b) = j b
```

How can I recognize the pattern of `Coproducts` corresponding to the code above?

Comment: Btw, the first definition is equivalent to `liftA2 (,)`, and the second definition is equivalent to the `either` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases, `factorizer` is the factorizer. From the blog post:

> A (higher order) function that produces the factorizing function m from two candidates is sometimes called the factorizer.

The pattern is that in both cases these functions give the *only* solution to certain equations.

For products, for every `f` and `g`, `factorizer f g` is the only function such that `fst . factorizer f g = f` and `snd . factorizer f g = g`.

For coproducts, for every `f` and `g`, `factorizer f g` is the only function such that `factorizer f g . Left = f` and `factorizer f g . Right = g`.

The existence of factorizers characterizes the `Either` and `(,)` types up to isomorphism. That provides an alternative way of describing products and sums that can be generalized to other categories (it's only about composition of morphisms). In contrast, a definition by `data (,) a b = (,) a b` and `data Either a b = Left a | Right b` is ad-hoc to a particular language.

Comment: I do not understand, why it is called `factorizer`?

Comment: It factorizes `f` and `g`.

Comment: Aha, that why it is called product.

Comment: No. The "product" operation that "factorizer" refers to here is function composition (or morphism composition in a more general category). The factorizer factorizes `f` as the composition `f = fst . factorizer f g` and `g` as the composition `g = snd . factorizer f g`.

Comment: Now am I confuse. I did not get the sense of a `factorizer`. What does  `factorizes` mean? Can you please explain it for dummy person like me.

Comment: "factorize" means "to write as a product". The meaning of "product" depends on the context. The best-known context is of course number theory, where the "product" operation is multiplication. In the context of category theory, we "factorize" morphisms as *compositions* of other, simpler morphisms.  The `factorizer` function returns a (common) factor of `f` and `g`.

Comment: If we can write `x = y . z` (for some operation `(.)`) we can say that `y` and `z` are factors of `x`. Another definition of "to factorize" is "to find the factors of something". What constitutes a good factor depends on the context. Often the factorization is meant to be unique in some sense.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a lot.